# Form is not validate using validate.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

Hi I succeed to make this code works but I don't know why this code is not working anymore anyone can help please on this?

Here this is my form

```
<form action="CreateUser" method="POST" id="subscribe">
     <br>
     <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><b>@</b></span>
                <label for="mail"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Adresse mail">
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
                 <label for="firstname"></label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Entrez votre prenom">
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
           <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
                 <label for="name"></label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Entrez votre nom">
           </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
           <div class="form-group">
                 <div class="input-group">
                       <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>
                       <label for="inputPassword"></label>
                       <input  id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe">

                  </div>                                  

           </div>    
           <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span></span>
                  <label for="txtConfirmPassword"></label>
                  <input  id="txtConfirmPassword" name="txtConfirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Retapez votre mot de passe">
           </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
             <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block"  name="submit" id="register" >Creer votre compte</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

And here this the validate function I did:

```
<script>
   $.validator.setDefaults({

        debug: true,
        success: "valid",

        highlight: function (element) {

            $(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');

        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');

        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorClass: 'text-danger',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());

            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    $.validator.addMethod("onlyletters", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-ZáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ._\s-]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please enter letters only.");

    $.validator.addMethod("passwd", function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Please enter letters and numbers only.");

    $('#subscribe').validate({
        rules: {
            inputPassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12,
                passwd: true
            },
            txtConfirmPassword: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 12,
                passwd: true,
                equalTo: "#inputPassword"
            },
            mail: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            firstname: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 20,
                onlyletters: true
            },
            name: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 20,
                onlyletters: true
            }

        },
        messages: {
            inputPassword: {
                required: "Password is required",
                minlength: "Your password must have 6 characters."
            },
            txtConfirmPassword: {
                required: "Password is required",
                minlength: "Your password must have 6 characters.",
                equalTo: "Your password doesn't match."
            },
            mail: {
                required: "Email is required",
                email: "Your mail address should be like user@example.com"
            }
        }
    });

    $('#register').click( function() {
        // Error checking here.
        if ($('div.error').is(':visible')) {
            return false; 
        }else{

        }
    });
</script>
```

And the imported jquery plugin

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

The plugin are imported from a previous page index.html and this form is loading from a modal

Comment: What exactly is happening when you try to run it?

Comment: Check your error console, I think you have a mistake in your click event handler!

Comment: You are trying to leach the plugin directly from the jQuery Validate website, `http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js`; however, the developer already provides [CDN links anyone can use for free](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js).  If you inspect your links above, you'll see that they'll auto-redirect to the CDN links.  For reliability, simply use the CDN links in the first place... don't leach or expect the developer's server to always auto-redirect.

Comment: Otherwise, your code, EXACTLY as you've posted it above, is working:  http://jsfiddle.net/0uom4wa8/

Comment: Yes I tried it also on jsfiddle and it's working I will move link to cdn to see if it help thx a lot for your trouble shooting

Answer (score 0):

Your click event handler is not correct.

```
$('#register').click( function() {
    // Error checking here.
    if ($('div.error').is(':visible')) {
        return false; 
    }else{

    });// This needs to be removed!!!!!

    }

});
```

**Working code:**

```
$('#register').click( function() {
    // Error checking here.
    if ($('div.error').is(':visible')) {
        return false; 
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Mivaweb, thx for your feedback but can you tell me where because I don't see missing }

Comment: @sadill View my answer in the first code block I have comment the line that needs to be removed. You have a `});` to much in your code.

Comment: Oh ok no it was an error during copy paste in stackoverflow of course in the code it was not the case. But he form are still not validate

Comment: Ok, can you change this in your question so its clear for everyone? Also do you see other errors in your error console?

Comment: I tested the code directly to a page including all plugins and it's working seems the problem is due to using modal but I don't understand why. I tried to import the plugin directly in the modal but no way it's not validating. please anyone help on this problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem on your `.click()` syntax, [here is the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/LztmxqL6/) in a JSFiddle.

Your error was a `}` and `)` problem.

Comment: Hi rémi, thx for your help but I still cannot see where is the prob can you tell me where please

Comment: Ok, i don't really enderstant what's not working here, in the JSFiddle i just pasted here: http://jsfiddle.net/LztmxqL6/. The validation messages are displayed pretty well..

Comment: the jquery function is not executing when content is loaded into modal from remote file I cannot see why